# Remove or adding additional string to a query

Tags: sql-server

In Table 1, I have below data:

```
Stock_no    Description
245685      Item1 Description
958565      Item2 Description
```

In Table 2, I have:

```
Barcode         Item_no
48002456854582  000245685
48003658458693  000958565
```

In my query, I would like to `JOIN` the two tables, `stock_no` of table 1 is similar to the `item_no` of Table 2.

Is there a way where I could truncate 0's to the `stock_no` of Table1, or remove the leading 0's of Table2?

What I have so far:

```
SELECT A.stock_no, B.barcode, A.description
FROM A.Table1
  JOIN B.Table2 ON A.stock_no = B.item_no
```

Because of the leading 000 of `item_no` in Table2, the above query would not work.

Comment: cast(item_no as int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do, but this will not use index if any exists:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1 t1
        JOIN Table2 t2 ON CAST(t1.stock_no AS INT) = CAST(t2.item_no AS INT)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use subtring method like :

```
select substring(ColumnName, patindex('%[^0]%',ColumnName), 10)
```

Your select should look like this:

```
SELECT A.stock_no, B.barcode, A.description
 FROM A.Table1 JOIN B.Table2
 ON A.stock_no = substring(B.item_no,patindex('%[^0]%',B.item_no),10)
```

The second parameter '10' is max lenght of you item_no column